# What is the correct form of "from" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

This is the sentence I would like to say in Italian: *"He does not come from the United States"* *(formal)*. I think it is:

> Lui non viene dagli Stati Uniti.

What is the correct word for ***from*** in this instance?
I know it has to be plural, I think because of the plural 'Stati', but I am at sea, here!
Is it one of these, or something else? Why?

> - dagli
> - delle
> - dalle

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Msfolly!

Comment: To be more formal I'd use *Egli* instead of *Lui* or also, if the context permits it, *Questi* (You need an introductive sentence as in *Il Sig. Bianchi è stato fermato al varco bagagli. Questi non viene dagli Stati Uniti*

Comment: Thank you for all the information.  That was very helpful! Is there anything else I need to do, now?

Comment: To accept an answer you have to click on the check mark that is beside the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Lui non viene dagli Stati Uniti" is correct.

"Da" can be combined with each of the 6 forms of the article "the":

- "da" + "lo" -> "dallo" (M, S, used when the next word starts with a vowel, z-, x-, y-, pt-, gn-, pn- or the so called "s impura", which is s+consonant)
- "da" + "il" -> "dal" (masculine, singular, used in the remaining cases)
- "da" + "la" -> "dalla" (feminine, S)
- "da" + "gli" -> "dagli" (M, P, used as "lo")
- "da" + "i" -> "dai" (M, plural, used as "il")
- "da" + "le" -> "dalle" (F, P)

Indeed, "Stati" is plural, masculine (most of the nouns ending in -i are masculine and plural) and starts with "s" + consonant, hence we use "dagli".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @PaoloFranchi!

Answer (score 6):

> Lui non viene **dagli** Stati Uniti.

is the right option, as you wrote. Here using *dagli* is correct since the compound preposition is followed by a plural and masculine noun, *Stati*.

---

- *Delle* is not appropriate: the preposition *di* can be used to specify a provenience, but mainly if followed by the name of a city, *e.g.:*

  > Sono **di** Napoli *(I'm from Naples)*;
- *dalle* must be followed by a feminine and plural noun:

  > Lui non viene **dalle** Azzorre *(He does not come from the Azores)*.